# Unable to use filter on an iterable RDD in pyspark

Tags: python, list, filter, pyspark, iterable

I'm trying to apply a function that filters out certain values in a dataset based on ranges of data in another dataset. I've performed a few groupBys and joins, so the format of the parameter I'm passing into the function has two Iterables, and goes as follows:

```
g1 = g0.map(lambda x: timefilter(x[0]))
```

where x[0] is `<pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x23b6610>, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x23b6310>)`

When I enter the function `timefilter` I need to now be able to filter out the values in x[1] based on values in x[0]. But when I try the following (on both `twoList` and `twoRDD`, although I just show twoList here):

```
def timefilter(RDDList):
    oneList = list(RDDList[0])
    twoList = list(RDDList[1])
    twoRDD = RDDList[1]
    test = twoList.filter(lambda x: x[4]=='helloworld')
    return test
```

It gives me the following errors: `AttributeError: 'ResultIterable' object has no attribute 'filter'`
and then a bunch of errors after.

It seems as though I can't use filter on any format of the iterables, but feel like I'm missing something very simple. Is there a transform I'm missing in the function?

Comment: Apparently `RDDList` is not a list of RDD. So you can't do what you do.

Comment: @fl00r I convert the Iterable RDD to a list in the function. While debugging what's going on, I just returned "return oneList" and on doing a collect on g1, it printed out a list of lists so that part seems to work fine. I'm not able to figure out why I can't treat the list(RDD) as a list and filter on it

Comment: Because there is no `list.filter()` in python. You could try a list comprehension, e.g., `[x for x in lst if x >= 0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that filtering on an iterable RDD isn't possible, so I just used the python in-built filter function. Something along the lines of the following: `filter(lambda x: x[1] in oneList, twoList)`.